# Shared data between fragment (parent and child listviews)

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, filtering

I have implemented a `listview` inside a `fragment` (detail explanation below), I wasn't sure if there is a better approach to this. Anyone can see my approach and suggest to me what is the best way to achieve it without having code clutter. Also, a gif animation of the desired result attached.

What I want to do, When the user taps on a detailed search, the user will see a list of categories, each category has a subcategory and more than one item can be ticked from each category. After the user goes back to the `main fragment`, he will have selected items will be available in main `fragment`. Then based on user selected data i can run search query.

**Desired result**

[image]

**Filter fragment**

```
public class FilterFragment extends Fragment {

    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private ListView lv;
    private List<Cats> categoryList;
    private String[] 

groupArray = {"Category1", "Category2", "Category3"};
    private String[][] childArray = {{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"},
            {"Video1", "Video2", "Video3"}, {"Audio1", "Audio2", "Audio3"}};

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

    lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    List<Cats> categoryData = null;
    if(getArguments()!=null){
        // data = (String[]) getArguments().getSerializable("strArray");
        categoryList = (List<Cats>)  getArguments().getSerializable("CATEGORY_LIST");
    }
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener = null;

    // If no data received means this is the first activity
    if (categoryData == null) {
        categoryData = categoryList;
        clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                FilterFragment newFragment = new FilterFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("strArray", childArray[position]);
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        };
    }

    // get data from the table by the ListAdapter
    ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_filter_item_row, categoryData);

    lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

    return root;
}
}
```

I will take back selected entries via `bundles` to the `main fragment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally found a soluton to this. How i approached is to use a sharedViewModel among fragments.

Using SharedViewModel, we can communicate between fragments. If we consider two fragments, both the fragments can access the ViewModel through their activity. Here is a preview, i have uploaded a demo application and code to github so everyone can have access and be able to modfiy the fragments.

[image]

**SharedViewModel**

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<CharSequence> text = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setText(CharSequence input) {
        text.setValue(input);
    }
    public LiveData<CharSequence> getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

get sharedViewModel data inside Fragment

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                editText.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }
```

Above is simplified concept, you can modify based on your need. please refer to github for complete code.

github: https://github.com/amirdora/FragmentSharedViewModel

Comment: And thanks for your input too on this answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom adapter, It's pretty easy to follow

In your fragment create a List

```
 public List<Cats> selectedData = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your adapter pass the reference of your fragment

```
YourFragment fragment;
 List<Cats> categoryData;
 public YourAdapter(YourFragment fragmet, List<Cats> categoryData){
     this.fragment = fragment;
     this.categoryData = categoryData;
 }
```

In your adapter inside onBindViewHolder

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position){
     holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
         if(isChecked)
              fragment.selectedData.add(categoryData.get(position));
     });
}
```

Comment: actually there are more lists to be maintained, 3 more lists like this. The idea to have a seperate lists inside each fragment and taking back data to main fragment is what makes me reconsider my initial approach. I want to efficiently maintain selected data. How do you suggest i move selected list to main fragment?

Comment: If you want to move the List<Cats> then it will be better you do how I did in the answer, if you 3 different listview and they all have the same data you can a single custom adapter but if you different data you'l need multiple adapters, however regardless of the data you can do it in a single adapter but that would be messy, The problem you're in is  the listview only detects the clicks on it's items not it's subitems, if you want the subitems to work you diffidently need a custom adapter, it might sound like a heckle but you'll be very happy once you know how custom adapters work.